# Azure Cosmos(MongoDB API) - Errors from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using Spark REPL Shell to test the connection to Cosmos DB

```
./spark-shell --master local[4] --jars /home/Flexplmadm/Downloads/lib/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://plum-dev-azure-cosmosdb:fd0f9d0f90fd==@xyz-dev-azure-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb" --conf  "spark.mongodb.input.collection=Users" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:0.3

import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
val UsersDF = MongoSpark.load(sc)
```

But I am getting the below error, can someone tell me if I am doing anything wrong

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing database name. Set via the 'spark.mongodb.input.uri' or 'spark.mongodb.input.database' property
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.databaseName(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:260)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.databaseName(ReadConfig.scala:42)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:70)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:42)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:124)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:42)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:113)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:42)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:100)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:42)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:66)
  at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:42)
  at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$.load(MongoSpark.scala:65)
  ... 49 elided
```

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDb is db account, so you need to manually create database. Then after correctly config properties, you should be able to connect to it. But CosmosDb is just working as Mongo, but not a real mongo. So you need to check the doc for detailed mongo feature you want to use.